# android check visibility of button after on click

Tags: android, button

when i click a button i call a function that make button invisible when i am connecting to server. the problem i cannot check if the visibility of the button has been modified.

```
 login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                socket.connect();
                if (login_btn.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    Clink.show(EspacePersonnelActivity.this, "veuillez verifier les parametres de connexion");

                }
            }

        });
```

after socket.connect if i receive this event

```
 //Réception message
        socket.on("EVT_ReponseOKConnexionZEP", new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(final Object... args) {

                String data = (String) args[0];
                Log.i("message :", data);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        zepLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner_green);
                        logout_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        login_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
                });

            }


        });
```

the problem is login_btn is visible before clicking, and the codition always return true.
i want to check if button is always visible or not after clicking on it.

Comment: where do you set you button as invisible?

Comment: i edit my question, in fact the view of button become GONE but the problem i can't check that inside the function on click

Comment: Why don't you deactivate the button? As soon as its pushed deactivate it so no further events are accepted. Then as the results come in activate it again if the request failed.

Answer (score 0):

All network related operations should be done on background thread. Looking at your code, it looks like when you call socket.connect(), connection will be established in the background thread. Because connection will be established in background thread, UI thread moves forward and executes if (login_btn.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) statement. Because you are setting login_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE), after establishing the connection which will be executed after if (login_btn.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) is called, login_btn visibility is always visible. If you want to display a message after the connection is established then you have to move the code inside your run() method or else if you want to display the message before/ while establishing the connection then you have to move Click.show() above socket.connect() statement.